# How to force re-download of page on back button click

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem: I have two webpages, `a.php` and `b.php`. The first page displays a list of items from a database, and the other page updates it and sends the user back to the previous page (by using `window.history.back()`).

However, when I go from `a.php` to `b.php`, update some entries in the database and go back, the list does not update without reloading the page manually. Is there any way that would allow me to either detect when the page is loaded as a result of a back button action and reload with JavaScript, or just tell the browser to update it automatically?

Comment: Is there a reason why your using JavaScript? This wouldn't happen if you used PHP etc...

Comment: @Jleagle As I said below, I am making a web app for mobile, and if I used redirects in PHP (or JavaScript, or anything else, really), it would just make the history too long, so that the user would have to click the back button too many times to get out of it.

Comment: I didn't think PHP redirects added to the browsers history. Ideally it sounds like you should use ajax to call b.php and then update the correct cell on success.

Comment: @Jleagle I'm pretty sure they are: if you have page `a` which redirected to page `b`, page `b` would still be added to the browser history. And AJAX seems like a possible solution, I might try to use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a.php 's headers to forbid any kind of caching - that way, the browser should reload the page when it re-enters it.

The most relevant HTTP response headers are Cache-control and Expires.

Comment: I have tried this, both by sending the headers from PHP and by using HTML meta tags, however, it still doesn't work...

Comment: @Frxstrem: Hmmm, strange. Alas (as we've seen numerous times), most browsers only uphold the standards when it's convenient to them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `window.history.back`. Use `location.href` to jump to `a.php`.

Comment: I have thought about using `location.href`, however, I am making a web app for mobile devices, and by using `location.href` (or something similar) the user would just end up having to press the back button very many times to get out of it.

Comment: can u add something similar to `onPageLoad` event on the page u go back to?

Comment: Another solution may be to reload the current page or post data to it. `b.php` can then just include `a.php` instead of doing its own stuff. And because you're reloading the page from a browser's perspective, it will probably not get recorded in the history. You will still have `b.php` there, but maybe that's not too bad..